# Table-stripped set same background color for special tr

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table that contains 4 rows in a cell separated with br. 
I do it with the br tag because all rows should have the same background color. But if the Screen is to small, it makes an automatic line break. So now my idea was to set every row in a separate tr and td tag but how can i give them the same background color?

**Answer below in this post**

Here is my example that's displayed up to three TR elements dynamically with table-striped.

```
<tr>
    <td width="30%">
      Question1<br />
      Question2<br />
      Question3<br />
      Question4
    </td>

   <td>
      Answer1<br />
      Answer2<br />
      Answer3<br />
      Answer4
   </td>
</tr>
```

Here I have snippet from the full table, the following rows after the three blogs should be striped with the right colors.

```
<table class="table table-striped">
 <tr> <!-- First paired Block White Background-->
    <td width="30%">
      Question1<br />
      Question2<br />
      Question3<br />
      Question4
    </td>           
   <td>
      Answer1<br />
      Answer2<br />
      Answer3<br />
      Answer4
   </td>
</tr>
 <tr> <!-- IF given show Second paired Block Grey Background-->
    <td width="30%">
      Question1<br />
      Question2<br />
      Question3<br />
      Question4
    </td>           
   <td>
      Answer1<br />
      Answer2<br />
      Answer3<br />
      Answer4
   </td>
</tr>
 <tr> <!-- IF given show Thirth paired Block White Background-->
    <td width="30%">
      Question1<br />
      Question2<br />
      Question3<br />
      Question4
    </td>           
   <td>
      Answer1<br />
      Answer2<br />
      Answer3<br />
      Answer4
   </td>
</tr>
<tr> <!-- grey Background if third block above is showing else white background-->
    <td width="30%">Other content</td>
    <td>other content</td>
</tr>
<tr> <!-- grey Background if row above is white else grey background-->
    <td width="30%">Other content</td>
    <td>other content</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**Update and Answer** (can't use the answer function):
Thanks to everybody, all your examples was very useful!
Now I give all blocks the colors white an grey, then I insert an empty tr after every block to use the table-striped class in every further row.

```
<table class="table table-striped">
<tr>
        <td width="30%" style="background: #f9f9f9;">Question1</td>
        <td style="background: #f9f9f9;">Answer1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="30%" style="border: 0px; background: #f9f9f9">Question2</td>
    <td style="border: 0px; background: #f9f9f9;">Answer2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="30%" style="border: 0px; background: #f9f9f9;">Question3</td>
    <td style="border: 0px; background: #f9f9f9;">Answer3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="30%" style="border: 0px; background: #f9f9f9;">Question4</td>
    <td style="border: 0px; background: #f9f9f9; padding-top: 0px;">Answer4</td>
</tr>
<tr></tr><!-- Set automatic bg color with table-striped -->
<tr>
        <td width="30%" style="background: #fff;">Question1</td>
        <td style="background: #fff;">Answer1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="30%" style="border: 0px; background: #fff">Question2</td>
    <td style="border: 0px; background: #fff;">Answer2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="30%" style="border: 0px; background: #fff;">Question3</td>
    <td style="border: 0px; background: #fff;">Answer3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="30%" style="border: 0px; background: #fff;">Question4</td>
    <td style="border: 0px; background: #fff; padding-top: 0px;">Answer4</td>
</tr>
<tr></tr><!-- Set automatic bg color with table-striped -->
<tr>
    <td width="30%">other</td>
    <td>content</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add a background property to the `tr`:

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse; /* to remove gaps between rows and cells */
}

table tr {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Question1</td>
    <td>
      Answer1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Question2</td>
    <td>
      Answer2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Question3</td>
    <td>
      Answer3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you, i have updated my example to make my questions cleaner

Answer (score 0):

That's right, ideally you should be using a separate tr for each row. And then style it via css using:

```
<table>
<tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
<tr><td>World</td></tr>
</table>

table tr
{
background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: thank you, i have updated my example to make my questions cleaner

Answer (score 0):

Add `question` and `answer` classes to you `td` elements like

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="question">
      Question1
    </td>
    <td class="answer">
      Answer1
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="question">
      Question2</td>
    <td class="answer">
      Answer2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="question">
      Question3
    </td>
    <td class="answer">
      Answer3
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

then in CSS you can write:

```
td .question {
  background-color: red;
}

td .answer {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

**Edit after question is updated:**

Add class `odd` and `even` alternatively to every row

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <tr class="even"> <!-- First paired Block White Background-->
      <td width="30%">
        Question1<br />
        Question2<br />
        Question3<br />
        Question4
      </td>           
    <td>
        Answer1<br />
        Answer2<br />
        Answer3<br />
        Answer4
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="odd"> <!-- IF given show Second paired Block Grey Background-->
      <td width="30%">
        Question1<br />
        Question2<br />
        Question3<br />
        Question4
      </td>           
    <td>
        Answer1<br />
        Answer2<br />
        Answer3<br />
        Answer4
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="even"> <!-- IF given show Thirth paired Block White Background-->
      <td width="30%">
        Question1<br />
        Question2<br />
        Question3<br />
        Question4
      </td>           
    <td>
        Answer1<br />
        Answer2<br />
        Answer3<br />
        Answer4
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="odd"> <!-- grey Background if third block above is showing else white background-->
      <td width="30%">Other content</td>
      <td>other content</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="even"> <!-- grey Background if row above is white else grey background-->
      <td width="30%">Other content</td>
      <td>other content</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

then in CSS you can write:

```
tr .even {
  background-color: white;
}

tr .odd {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

Comment: thank you, i have updated my example to make my questions cleaner

Comment: But if the thirth block isn showing it has "odd" in the second block and "odd" in the content block after it. You know what i mean?

Answer (score 0):

Oh I see. This is just a case of using css odd and even:

```
tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: green;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: red;
}
```